# How to add multiple roles to an existing user form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to figure to how I can add multiple roles to a policy, individual to each user, and then assign that policy to user instead of only assigning one role. I currently have a role creation and assign role to user. I understand that the manay-to-many may be needed to be implemented here and has_many :through but I am having trouble understanding the logic behind it

So in my db/migrate folder I currently have an AddRoleToUser and in my RolesController i have a set_role

```
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_role
      @role = Role.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def role_params
      params.require(:role).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check this topic on rails doc:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

I also can try to help you if you have any more specific question :D

Comment: could i possibly message you

Comment: Yes. Or use this comments

Comment: could i share my project with you on github? So I want to create a policy controller, put it into my users form, and in the policy, I want tot be able to assign many roles, how could I do this?